# margin and width issue in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, cross-browser

I am setting my div's `margin` and `width`, all `margin` and `width` are showing properly in Firefox and Internet Explorer. However, Google Chrome it's not working.
If I INSPECT the page in Chrome and adjusting my `margin`, then it shows effect but if I update my CSS then it does not work.

I am also using `-webkit-margin-start: 44px;` but nothing is working .

my CSS is as follows : -

```
#main {
  position:relative;
  width:1200px !important;
  min-height:800px;
  margin:44px auto;
  top: 7px;
  left: 2px;
  -webkit-margin-start: 44px;             
}
```

any suggestions, also it is not working in this `@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {` if i declare margin ...

screen shots as follows :- 
[image] for chrome

for Firefox [image]

Thanks in advance.

chrome version : 62.0.3202.62

Comment: After updating your css did you try clearing the cache in chrome?

Comment: you use `margin:44px auto` which means `margin-top:44px margin-right:auto margin-bottom:44px margin-left:auto` . But `-webkit-margin-start:44px` is refering to `margin-left`

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @MihaiT thanks , but how to refer  margin-top for google chrome .

Answer (score 0):

As i said in my comment, you use `margin:44px auto` which means `margin-top:44px margin-right:auto margin-bottom:44px margin-left:auto` . But `-webkit-margin-start:44px` is refering to `margin-left`

`margin-top` is `-webkit-margin-before`. BUT this refers mostly to text margin and it's depending on the writing-mode,direction and text-orientation, as you can see here [margin dev moz](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline-start) or you can search SO for similar questions

Your code seems to work ( see snippet below ). The only problem i see there is that you use position and margin. ( top,left + margin ) . I suggest you either use position either margin. For example, don't use `top:7px` but instead use `margin:51px auto 44px` ( if you want to keep the bottom margin as 44px ).

Without anymore code from you, there is nothing else we can do. If the problem persists, please add a working snippet that replicates your problem

I changed in the code below the `webkit-margin-start` with `webkit-margin-before` as explained before

```css
#main {
  position:relative;
  width:1200px !important;
  min-height:800px;
  margin:44px auto;
  top: 7px;
  left: 2px;
  -webkit-margin-before: 44px;     
  background:red;
}
body { margin:0}
```

```html
<div id="main">

</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your response , today I checked the problem is not only with margin or height but with whole css file  , for eg . cursor shape not changing in chrome  . also colors of div has no effect in chrome ..

Comment: @speedyraz seems like you have a problem that we, without any specific info from you, can't solve

Comment: I edited my question , css file is same ,although your code snippet working properly in both browser , but nothing works in chrome.